# Simple calculation in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to calculate Reynolds Number using VB.NET

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim vis As Integer
Dim Den As Integer
Dim hd As Integer
Dim vl As Integer
Dim re As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    vis = Int(TextBox1.Text)
    Den = Int(TextBox2.Text)
    hd = Int(TextBox4.Text)
    vl = Int(TextBox5.Text)
    re = (Den * vl * hd) / vl
    TextBox3.Show(re)

End Sub

End Class
```

See my UI [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjpoz.png).

Why I am still getting an error message "too many arguments" ?

Comment: If you want to post `re` to a textbox, it is `TextBox3.Text = re.ToString()`.  You should turn on Option Strict though - the result of `(Den * vl * hd) / vl` will be Double, not Integer

Comment: If I am correct, that **is not how to calculate Reynolds number**. I would look more ***https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number*** there first before trying this...

Comment: BTW, `.Show()` just sets the .Visible property to true.

Comment: Many thanks. The program now works.

Comment: I will correct the equation as you advised

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong in the code you posted, firstly the calculation is wrong for Reynolds number. Second, please turn on `Option Strict` as with your current code it would not compile. Third please use conventional naming conventions it makes it difficult in the long run... There's more but not the point...

**Suggested Solution**

Variable Declaration Meaning:

- d = Diameter of the pipe
- v = Velocity of Liquid
- u = Viscoscity of the Liquid
- p = Density of the Liquid
- tot = The Reynolds Number

  ```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim d,v,u,p,tot As Single

   If Single.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,d) AndAlso Single.TryParse(TextBox2.Text,v) AndAlso Single.TryParse(TextBox3.Text,u) AndAlso Single.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,p) Then
     tot = (d * v * p) / (u * 0.001)

     MessageBox.Show(tot.ToString) 
     'OR
     TextBox3.Text = tot.ToString
   End If
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: `TextBox3.Show(tot.ToString)`?

Comment: @Plutonix meant to add a `MessageBox`...nice catch :)

Comment: Why not show him how to put it in a cleverly named textbox (e.g. `TextBox13`) since that was his actual question

Answer (score 0):

The Int function does not do type conversion. It simply returns the integral portion of a value (14.8 would become 14). To do this conversion, you want to use CInt, if you guarantee that the incoming text really is a number.

Since you are using user supplied values, you might want to use some error correction.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, vis) AndAlso _
       Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Den) AndAlso _
       Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, hd) AndAlso _
       Integer.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, vl) Then

       'Do your calculation
    Else
       'There is some kind of error. Don't do the calculation
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not going to address whether your formula is correct or not.

Comment: Just a suggestion, the `TryParse` is wrong you are using. It takes a String and Integer, not Integer/String.

Comment: Yeah. I just typed it in without going back to an IDE to verify. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I tried to do error correction as you suggested. This is the code: